# How to list active game center matches of other players?

Tags: iphone, ios, game-center

I'm working on multiplayer card game.

With this code player is adding new match:

```
-(void)addNewMatch {

    NSLog(@"addNewMatch");

    GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];

    request.maxPlayers = 2;
    request.minPlayers = 2;

    [GKTurnBasedMatch findMatchForRequest:request withCompletionHandler:^(GKTurnBasedMatch *match, NSError *error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.localizedDescription );
        } else {
            NSLog(@"match found!");
            [self.vc dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
            [[GCTurnBasedMatchHelper sharedInstance] turnBasedMatchmakerViewController:nil didFindMatch:match];

        }
    }];
}
```

How can I list all active matches (rooms) of other players?